# Create a button to toggle flash when taking a photo

Tags: swift

So I'm creating a camera app and i want to have a flash button for on/off/auto and then when the user hits the shutter butter the flash will go off if enables. I created a button for the flash but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
@IBAction func didTouchFlashButton(sender: UIButton) {
}
```

This is my button and this is my button to take the photo

```
 @IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {

//        UIImagePicker.cameraFlashMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashMode.On

    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
                self.photos.append(image)
                print("Photo saved to array")
                print(self.photos)
//                    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            }

        })
    }
}
```

So basically I want the button to tell whether to use flash or not and depending on what the user decides it will be initiated in the `didPressTakePhoto`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1388116-flashmode

Answer (score 0):

```
//get image picker
let picker:UIImagePickerController = ... 

picker.cameraFlashMode = sender.isSelected ? .on : .off
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.